# ENOENT no such file or directory error in cloud function upload image

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to cloud functions and working on creating a function that (among other things) uploads an image from Flutter image_picker to cloud storage. Below is the relevant cloud fn code:

```
  // upload image to storage
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
        const destination = data.storageCollection + '/' + data.itemID;

      
        const filePath = data.filePath;

        console.log('filePath is ' + data.filePath);

        await bucket.upload(filePath, {
          destination: destination,
          gzip: true,
        });
```

I'm getting this error:

> functions error in uploadProductPic: [firebase_functions/internal] project: undefined. Function: uploadImage. Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/data/user/0/com.appIdentifier.here/cache/a2b21481-ab56-4af5-bc97-4c2d050107e12579524263120800910.jpg'

Maybe I'm just bad at storage directories, but I'm pretty sure that's the absolute path. I've also tried other combinations:

```
'data/user/0/com.appIdentifier.here/cache/a2b21481-ab56-4af5-bc97-4c2d050107e12579524263120800910.jpg'
```

```
'cache/a2b21481-ab56-4af5-bc97-4c2d050107e12579524263120800910.jpg'
```

```
'/cache/a2b21481-ab56-4af5-bc97-4c2d050107e12579524263120800910.jpg'
```

And nothing has worked. Can someone tell my why my path is wrong here? I'm just getting it from the .path property of an XFile. I've found some similar stack posts but haven't yet found a solution.

Edit:
Here's my clientside code

```
  Future<void> uploadProductPic(String productID, XFile file) async {
try {
  await functions.httpsCallable('uploadImage').call(<String, String>{
    "filePath": file.path,
    "itemID": productID,
    "storageCollection": "productPic",
    "itemCollection": "products"
  });
} catch (e) {error catching stuff}
```

And here's my full cloud function:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} filePath
 * @param {string} itemID
 * @param {string} storageCollection
 * @param {string} itemCollection
 */

exports.uploadImage = functions.region("australia-southeast1")
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
 
  // Only allow authorised users to execute this function.
  if (!(context.auth && context.auth.token)) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        "permission-denied",
        "Must be an administrative user to upload an image."
    );
  }

  try {

    // upload image to storage
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    const destination = data.storageCollection + '/' + data.itemID;

    const filePath = data.filePath;
   
    await bucket.upload(filePath, {
      destination: destination,
      gzip: true,
    });

    // get download url
    const url = await bucket.getDownloadURL(destination);

 // upload url to database
        const firebaseRef = data.itemCollection + '/' + data.itemID;
        await firebaseTools.firestore.updateDoc(firebaseRef, {'imageURL': url});

  } catch (err) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "project: " +
  process.env.GCP_PROJECT +
  ". Function: uploadImage. Error: " + String(err));
  }
}
);
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you add your client-side code to your question? You appear to be uploading a string containing the path to the file on the user's device instead of streaming the binary data of that file to the server. Can you also include the full cloud function definition? It's unclear if you are using `https.httpsCallable`, `https.onRequest` or another type of cloud function.

Comment: Ahhh that's exactly what I'm doing - somehow I totally missed the streaming to the server step in my googling! I'll do a bit of research and see if I can figure that out, but any pointers from you will be very much appreciated. Thank you @samthecodingman!

Comment: If you want to keep using `https.onCall` you'll need to convert the file to data URI on the client side, then use `bucket().file(/* filename */).save(/* uri */)` on the cloud functions side. You could also switch out to a `https.onRequest` to upload the file as part of a `multipart/form-data` request and then use `busboy` to parse the data - but this requires you to handle the authentication check yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions run on a fully remote machine in the cloud, not on the device where your app is installed.  It simply cannot access local files on the device.

If you want to upload a file from the app, you should use the Firebase Storage SDK for your app's platform, and not Cloud Functions.

Comment: Hey Doug! Until now I've been using the Firebase SDK, but I do some other tasks along with uploading the image that I'd like to avoid doing clientside. My understanding was that I can upload locally stored files to cloud storage based on this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions. Can you explain to me what filePath they're talking about in the docs if not a path to a local file?

Comment: Storage triggers let you run code in the cloud **after** a file was uploaded by a client app using the appropriate SDK.